# Using field calculator to delete specific contours

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, contour

I have 3 contour shapefiles with 25m, 50m and 100m equidistance. Now I want to delete in the 25m-shp-file every **50m and **00m contour and in the 50m-shp-file every **00 contour. How can I show them using the field calculator of qgis?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a contour value field, it should be possible to select **50m and **00m contours for later deletion using the following query with the modulo operator:

```
value % 50 = 0
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think for this to work the contour data has to be in a database (Spatialite preferred, in my case). Unless something has changed recently. N.

Comment: No this will work on any layer.

Comment: Is this a new feature?

Comment: I'm not sure when the modulo operator was introduced @nhopton. But I think it has been around for a few versions already.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to simply create a new field based on the modulo operator, %, of the contour value.

A more complex way would be to select the 25 layer, and then select by location all the contours of the 50 layer that overlap the selection.